# Доспех или доспехи?

Tags: лексика

«Надел доспех, и знамя взял». «Чтоб я ещё хоть раз надел доспехи!».

Оба слова обозначают одно и то же?

Comment: @anaka2005, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Автор вопроса знает, как пользоваться сайтом, так что Ваши подсказки излишние.

Comment: Автор вопроса на сайте недавно и вполне может не знать. Или Вы и про него  все знаете? А вот Expert  - модератор и вправе дать совет.

Comment: Он (она) уже помечал(а) мой вопрос как правильный, поэтому я сделал такой вывод.

Comment: Я задала вопрос и ушла спать, не дожидаясь ответа. Извините, не знала, что так делать нельзя.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В
 целом "доспех" и "доспехи" обозначают одно и тоже. Не могу согласиться,
 что форма единственного числа так уж редкоупотребительна, так как типы 
доспехов называют именно с помощью ее (*миланский, готический, 
максимильяновский доспех*). Также при рассмотрении доспехов как единого 
целого, а не как набора элементов защиты, тоже 
используют форму единственного числа, в обратном же случае - 
множественного.

Что касается ваших примеров, то желательно знать контекст в первом случае
 употребления, так как может быть, что доспехи были частично одеты и герой 
облачился из походного варианта доспехов в боевой.

Comment: Не одеты, а надеты :)

Comment: @Пересвет, доспехи, если говорить о средневековых, как раз как правило **одеты**, так как облачиться в них самостоятельно было почти невозможно.

Comment: @МаркИз, "одеты, так как облачиться в них самостоятельно было почти невозможно" => Но если доспехи были **одеты**, то во что?

Answer (score 3):

Да, это два варианта одного и того же слова. Форма "доспех" употребляется очень редко, гораздо более употребительна форма "доспехи".

Answer (score 2):

Ну, [[@Марк Из](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7)](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7) нам уже продемонстрировал со всей наглядностью, какие интересные люди эти историки; какие интересные эти лингвисты, я вам, к сожалению, продемонстрировать не могу, ибо к их числу не принадлежу, — могу лишь напомнить о том, что в числе лексических средств речевой выразительности существует известное под названием [*синекдоха*](http://literatura5.narod.ru/sinekdoha.html) —  использование единственного числа вместо множественного. Затрудняюсь сказать, имеет ли место использование означенного тропа в данном случае, — возможно, слова *доспех* и *доспехи* столь же близки по значению, как и слова *стих* и *стихи* или *божий дар* и *яичница*, но как бы то ни было, встретив в речи слово, употребленное в форме единственного числа, хотя в контексте обозначает оно скорее множество, не стоит сразу задумываться о присущем этой форме значении, отличном от значения, присущего форме множественного числа.

> Тут вряд ли можно назвать тропом. Когда говорят об одном комплекте доспехов чаще говорят "доспехи", рыцарь тоже облачится в "доспехи", а вот если в Рыцарском Зале Эрмитажа мы видим несколько полных комплектов, то каждый из них в отдельности будет "доспехом".

Ну вот я и говорю, что затрудняюсь сказать и право судить оставляю за Вами и прочими искушенными. Впрочем, Вы этим правом воспользовались и без моего высочайшего на то позволения.

Да, еще мне кажется, что, хотя трудящиеся в Рыцарском Зале Эрмитажа чувствуют принципиальную разницу в значении слов *доспех* и *доспехи*, употребленные как элементы общей лексики, эти слова взаимозаменяемы. По той причине, что в художественном, публицистическом, разговорном стиле речи возможно использование тропов. Поэтому, когда доспехом называется то, что в действительности является доспехами, не спешите впадать в состояние когнитивного диссонанса: возможно, автор анализируемых вами строк просто любитель высокопарного слога.

Вот, позвольте вам процитировать одного такого любителя:

*А если я не прав и лжет мой **стих**,*

*То нет любви — и нет стихов моих!*

Слова *стих* и *стихи* имеют совершенно разные значения, как я уже отметила выше. В данном случае речь идет скорее о ***стихах***, тем не менее Маршак, работая над переводом шекспировского сонета, употребил слово ***стих***, очевидно, как более свойственное поэтической речи.

Прекрасные стихи и замечательный вопрос!

Comment: Тут вряд ли можно назвать тропом. Когда говорят об одном комплекте доспехов чаще говорят "доспехи", рыцарь тоже облачится в "доспехи", а вот если в Рыцарском Зале Эрмитажа мы видим несколько полных комплектов, то каждый из них в отдельности будет "доспехом".

Answer (score 1):

У Ушакова: ДОСПЕ́ХИ, доспехов, ***ед. (редк.)*** доспех,доспеха, муж. ***(книжн. устар.).***
В большом толковом словаре под редакцией Кузнецова ( На грамоте .ру) ; ДОСПЕХИ, -ов; мн. (ед. доспех, -а; м.).  Как видите , без помет. 
По видимому, доспехи - это рыцарские латы. Доспех же - это одна из его частей.

Answer (score 0):

Ясно дело, слово *доспех* стоит в единственном числе, а слово *доспехи* — во множественном. Первая форм, мне кажется, вообще встречается крайне редко.